# Android: Get MY Contact info

Tags: java, android, contacts

I am able to retrieve contacts and all of their information, but in the Contact list I do not see "ME". I read that this was not supported, but t there was a ticket to Android about this (back in 2011?).

**Is it possible to retrieve MY contact card in Android?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because you don't have one unless the user added one.  Even if there is one, there's no promise of any actual data on it.  Not even phone number, since its possible for a phone to not know its own phone number.

Comment: OK, thats strange. For me, personally, I see a contact card called "ME" in the contacts app, but not on the Contacts picker and I did not add that contact.